# Mapping a 1 - many relation in a Django Rest Framework View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my DRF i want to map a customers/sercvices relation in the view.
So one Customer can have 0 - many services inside of it

My serializer class appears to be fine as inspired by [How to join two models in django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197964/how-to-join-two-models-in-django-rest-framework/43198182)

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Customer 
        fields = ['name' , 'phone' ,'email1' ... , 'service_id'] 


class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service 
        fields = ['service_name', 'product_name', ...]


class Customer_ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    service = ServiceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name' , 'phone1' , 'email1' ... 'service']
```

My Customer_ServiceSerializer class seems to be nested correctly

Im stuck on how i would show these combined models in the view as i have tried multiple things and come up stuck

```
class Customer_serviceListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
...

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Above is how i started my views but i am stuck on how to solve this problem

tried for example this [Serialize multiple models in a single view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700960/serialize-multiple-models-in-a-single-view)  / https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/06/20/django-tip-5-how-to-merge-querysets.html

but i get Customer objects arent iterable so how would i go about this

Thanks in advance

Edit

```
class Customer_serviceListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Customer_ServiceSerializer
    lookup_field= "name"
```

Need to do something in the views no? as currently as it is it will just display the customers with the service_id not the service details 
So i need to do something extra to make it work like that

Comment: Why do you think you need to do anything in the view? The serializer should just handle it.

Comment: Added an Edit at the botom

Comment: But you've done the "something extra", which is to define Customer_ServiceSerializer with `service = ServiceSerializer`.

Comment: Wouldnt i need that step to join the serializer classes but i cant map that structure in the views

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. What step? You are *already* joining the serializer classes.

Comment: In the views it only displays the customer data only not the service data aswell

Comment: What view? The Customer_serviceListAPIView is serializing to JSON based on the Customer_ServiceSerializer, which includes `service` as a sub-serializer. Are you sure you are actually going to a URL which points at Customer_serviceListAPIView?

Comment: yes i am doing that and navigating to that url returns customer with the respective services